# Converting variable categories into columns

Tags: r

I have a data.frame which basically looks like this:

```
question_id points
1   4
2   4
3   5
4   2
5   3
1   5
2   3
3   4
4   4
5   2
```

Variable question_id has 5 categories (1 to 5). I would like these categories to be columns, so that one row would mean one persons' answer:

```
q1  q2  q3  q4  q5
4   4   5   4   3
4   5   3   5   3
4   4   3   2   1
```

I tried to convert it to matrix, but it didn't work. As I am new to R (doing DataCamp course now), I am asking for help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it by myself (yay!) using reshape2 package. I learned about long/wide formatting. 
I had to transform it from long to wide, so I used dcast function. I also have added two more variables, which are date and order_id:

```
raw_wide <- dcast(raw, order_id + date ~ question_id, value.var = "points")
```

That's it. Thanks